Release Mode Issue with 64bit upgraded Application
I have upgraded a MFC application to 64bit from 32bit.
I am facing an issue in Release mode.
Issue is: In the print functionality, i have overridden a method OnPreparePrinting. Which has a argument CPrintInfo, and i am calling a method pi->SetMaxPage(1); But this calls is not working in release mode. Result it gives error in Release mode.
BOOL  ZMyView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pi)

Please let me know how do i debug and fix this issue. What could be the cause.
This is happening in a DLL which is added into application.
If i pass the CPrintInfo* pi to new separate DLL and call pi->SetMaxPage(1), then it works fine.
But it is not working in the main DLL. Need to fix in Main DLL since i don't want to add dependency DLL.

"it gives error" is not helpful. What is the error? Is it a compile time error or a run time error? But you have extremely valuable information: It works from another DLL. So study how your DLL calls the method differently from the other one. Maybe it is a header mismatch?

I mean , pi->SetMaxPage(1); basically set the page in print dialog. It does not set in release mode as it in Debug mode.

no one answered my question, is it something i am only doing this x86 to x64 configuration, and facing issue?

You said that "the call is not working in release mode", which implies that x64 debug mode works, which in turn suggests investigating differences between release and debug. That it works in another DLL means that you can look at the code generation and see what is different between release and debug. But your new comment suggests that it's not a debug/retail issue but an x86/x64 issue. Please clarify.
